# how to set default font name preety in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, ckeditor

I have to use 2 ckeditor at once , one for normal english and another for font-family: Preeti at once.Normal english ckeditor is no problem but for another one I want that to be default in it and not changeable by user too. How am I to do it. I was able to do using jquery change function. i.e. when I change the font using dropdown i call the jquery change function as follows.

```
$('#language').change(function(){
                    var lang_id = $(this).val();
                    var font_family= $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');
                    var lang  = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                    if($('#'+lang_id).size() < 1){
                            var html_data= '<div class="single_data clone" id="'+lang_id+'"><span class="remove">Remove</span><span class="language">In '+lang+'</span><div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" >Content Title : *</label><div class="controls"> <input type="hidden" name="language[]" value="'+lang_id+'"/><input style="font-family:'+font_family+';" class="span12 title" type="text" value="" name="title['+lang_id+']" /></div></div><div class="span12"><div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">Content</label><div class="controls"><textarea style="font-family:'+font_family+';" class="editor" name="description['+lang_id+']"></textarea></div></div></div></div>';
                            $('.multi_data').append(html_data);

                            var text_content = $('#'+lang_id).find('textarea.editor').ckeditor();
                            CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
                               ev.editor.setData('<span style="font-family:'+font_family+';">&shy;</span>');
                            });
                    }else{
                            alert('Content is already add for this language.');
                    }
        });
```

but I dont want the Preeti to load on change function but on default.i.e. one ckeditor with normal default english and another one with default font-family as Preeti.How am I to do it. Any idea/suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found one idea ... here

```
<textarea cols="100" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"><p> <span style="font-family:Preeti;">­description</span></p> </textarea>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with an CKEditor instance. 
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ); 
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ){ //set the background properties ev.editor.setData('<span style="font-family:Preeti">&shy;</span>'); 
}); 
</script>
```